# Testing two conditions in python. One condition is always true even when it is not supposed to be

Tags: python, function, if-statement, recursion, runtime-error

I am having difficulties getting this code to work. I am attempting to do the following.

1. When x is raised to a power of y, it needs to be true except with number 1.
2. Return true when x is divisible by y.

Problems.
I wrote this code but the problem is that when I input x=3 and y=3 I get and answer that x is the power of y which isn't true. Regardless of the number, if x == y it always says that x is power of y.

Question.

How would you make the corrections for this code?

```
def is_divisible(x, y):
    if x % y == 0:
        print("x is divisible by y")
        return True
    else:
        print("x is not divisible by y")
        print("x is not the power of y")
        return False


def is_power(x, y):
    if x == 1 or y == 1:  # code to test the base of 1
        return x == 1

    elif x % y == 0:
        print("x is the power of y")
        print("x is divisible by y")
    elif is_divisible(x, y) and is_power(x / y, y): # recursion of is_divisible. This will be true only if x/y
    # then x is the power of y.
        return 0.0
    else:
        return False
    


print(is_power(2, 2))

outputs

x is the power of y
x is divisible by y
None


print(is_power(27, 3))
x is the power of y
x is divisible by y
None
```

Comment: What is `is_power` supposed to test? Regardless, when `x % y == 0` (i.e., when `y` divides `x` evenly), you don't return anything; you just fall through to the end of the function where `None` is implicitly returned. Also, why does the function return `0.0` instead of a boolean value in the third case?

Comment: is_power must be true only if x = 27 is the power or y = 3 ( 3*3*3 = 27) with the exception of 1 which power of 1 is always 1. In this case, when I put x=2, y=2, it says x is the power of y but it is not true. 2 cant be the power of 2. that is the part I cant figure it out. Everything else seems to be working fine. I really want to answer the other question about the return 0.0 but Im fairly new to this and I am doing only what I have learned so far.